# How to send custom props to AdminJS.bundle()

Tags: node.js, react-props, adminjs, admin-bro

### Feature request

1. provide `download` feature where if i a filter is applied the triggered download should download filtered data in an excel sheet.

Their is an `api` when given `tableName` and `filter columns` it fetches that data returns.
But the issue with including that api in the action handler is, this handler runs in server environment which doesn't have access to window object to download the excel even if i have the data.

> But why `window` is required??

```js
  // for THIS.
  const newRes = await res.blob();
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([newRes]));
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute("download", `users.xlsx`);
  link.click();
```

> package.json

```json
  "@adminjs/express": "5.0.1",
   "@adminjs/prisma": "3.0.1",
   "@prisma/client": "4.8.1",
   "@tiptap/core": "^2.0.0",
   "@tiptap/pm": "^2.0.3",
   "adminjs": "6.7.4",
```

> Handler with download functionality

```js
handler(request, response, context) {
          console.log(filterQuery);
          fetch(`someApi/users`, {
            method: "GET",
            "Content-Type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats"
          })
            .then(async (res) => {
              const newRes = await res.blob();
              const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([newRes]));
              const link = document.createElement("a");
              link.href = url;
              link.setAttribute("download", `users.xlsx`);
              link.click();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log("ERR", err);
            })
            .finally(() => {
            });
          filterQuery = {};
          return true;
        },
```

> Custom Download Action

```js
 actions: {
      list: {
        // due to this hook i have the filter queries
        before: [saveFilterQueriesAFTER]
      },
      //custom action
      Download: {
        actionType: "resource", 
        icon: "Download",
        component: Adminjs.bundle("../../Components/Download.jsx")
      }
    }
```

> Function which gets the query params

**This func is required because when the custom action is triggered it changes the URL by which i
loose the filtered query params**

```js
function saveFilterQueriesAFTER(originalResponse) {
  let filters = Object.keys(originalResponse.query);
  if (filters.length > 0) {
    filters.map((filter) => {
      if (filter !== "page") {
        Object.assign(filterQuery, {
          [filter.slice(8)]: originalResponse.query?.[filter]
        });
       // { full_name: 'SHAHED' }
      }
    });
  }
  return originalResponse;
}
```

Now the filter queries i have accumulated in (`filterQuery`) i want to send it to this custom component so that i can access it and get data from the db using this filter queries, so is there any way i can send this props to the `Download` component.

### Another Way

- when `adminjs` itself is getting filtered data, i want to access that data directly and save it a variable instead of saving its filter queries which will any way get the same data from db.

  - if this possible
  - how to access that data?
  - how to send that data as props to my custom component `Download.jsx`